# Issue with image loading using Glide library in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I am trying to get movie list images from an api (tmdb) but I don't know if I'm using the api wrong or the **GLIDE**

This is the piece of code for Glide:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.apply {
        val movie = movies[position]
        val imageBase = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"

        Glide.with(holder.itemView)
            .load(imageBase + moviePoster)
            .error(R.mipmap.tvmovieposter)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.binding.moviePoster)
        movie
        movieTitle.text = movies[position].title
        MovieReleaseDate.text = movies[position].release_date
    }
}
```

These is the error:

> /Glide: Load failed for
> [https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView{995e7ba](https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView%7B995e7ba)
> V.ED....I. 0,0-  0,0  #7f080119 app:id/movie_poster} with size
> [300x400]     `your text``
>
> I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
> com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
> at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:98)

This is where I get URL:

```
interface MovieApiInterface {
        @GET("/3/movie/popular?api_key=90a54a6b7ac845f17b2b70d45f6c2851")
        fun getMovieList(): Call<MovieResponse>
}
```

and this is my data class:

```
@Parcelize
data class Movie(

    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String?,

    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String?,

    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    val poster_path: String?,

    @SerializedName("release_date")
    val release_date: String,
) : Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("", "", "", "")
}
```

Comment: It looks like your image URL may be incorrect.

Can you debug and see what exactly comes as the value for moviePoster

Update: Just add a log message to see the value for imageBase + moviePoster

Comment: The URL doesn't look right. You don't specify what `moviePoster` is, but either its contents are wrong or you are making an invalid reference. _androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView_ appended to the URL gives it away.

Comment: in .load(imageBase + moviePoster) code, seems moviePoster is an ImageView object instead of a string. Can you make sure passing the correct sub-url as string at the place of moviePoster variable in above code.

Comment: @RuchiraRandana
the video that I saw used the exact URL and it worked.this is the link to the video(minute 7:30)      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kKAgWUYHDo

Comment: @Cheticamp  can you be more specific?
Movie poster is an imageview in my recycler view that is supposed to hold the poster I get from api

Comment: ``.load(imageBase + moviePoster)`` should be ``.load(imageBase + movies[position]. poster_path)``

Comment: @OMiShah
I tried it. This is the error :  ```W/Glide: Load failed for https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500//1dviyIqBrbnigrbodIvfMQj8mJ0.jpg with size [300x400]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE ```

Comment: Post how the variable `moviePoster` is declared and how its value is set.

Comment: Now, the image URL is coming correct, issue with the internet. Have you added the Internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file? @kamyab

Comment: @OMiShah yes I have added internet permission already

Comment: If the URL is correct, see if you can use the URL to load the image into a browser. If you can then it is possible that the firewall is stopping your app if you are running it in an emulator. @kamyab

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is on the following line: `val movie = movies[position]`

From the way you use movies later on in `movies[position].title`, I am assuming "movies" is an array of some sort of data class.

What part of that data class contains the URL for the poster?

It would be more clear if you posted your "Movie" class. I can see that it has a `title` and a `release_date`

If this is the Udacity nanodegree course that I did, you are looking for `poster_path` so the first line where your mistake is, should probably be something like `val movie = movies[position].poster_path`

But check your Movie data class to be sure.

Comment: I edited and added my Movie data class.
and I tried your solution but didn't work

Comment: Your `.load(imageBase + moviePoster)` looks wrong too. Once you have val
`val movie=movies[position].poster_path`, then you need `.load(imageBase + movie)`

You probably want to wrap the whole Glide command to make sure that the poster_path is not empty before making Glide do its thing too.

Comment: thanks for giving me solutions,
this didnt work either

Comment: Are the errors you are getting the same or different?

Comment: It's the same..